# assign variable for query according to array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, associative-array

I want to take a PHP variable from a query

```
?q=aaa
```

and define a variable in JS according to an associative array:

```
{
    "aaa": "111",
    "bbb": "222",
    "ccc": "333"
};
```

so that if

```
var oldVariable = '<?php echo $q; ?>' ;
```

then

```
var newVariable = ...   // '222' when $q is 'bbb'
```

Comment: Could you explain it again? I don't understand.

Comment: What's the original value of `$q` ?

Comment: The associative array is server or client side?

Comment: $q = query string. when $q = aaa, then $newVariable = 111 . 

when $q = bbb, then $newVariable = 222 . etc. 

maybe .val() to find $oldVariable's value in the array?

Comment: Then it's just `var value = '<?php echo $array[$_GET['q']]; ?>';`.

Comment: sorry, I meant client side; Jari below has what I need: a way to receive input in PHP and assign it a variable according to a JS array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy:

```
<script>
<?php $q =  (isset($_GET['q'])) ? $_GET['q'] : "default" ;?>

var arr = {
    "aaa": "111",
    "bbb": "222",
    "ccc": "333"
};

var oldVariable = '<?php echo $q ; ?>' ;
var newVariable = (typeof arr['<?php echo $q ; ?>'] != "undefined") ? arr['<?php echo $q ; ?>'] : "No var from get" ;

alert(newVariable) ;

</script>
```